# AddIdentity vs AddIdentityCore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core, you can add various services for identification: `AddDefaultIdentity`, `AddIdentity` and `AddIdentityCore`.

What's the difference between `AddIdentity` and `AddIdentityCore`?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`AddIdentityCore` adds the services that are necessary for user-management actions, such as creating users, hashing passwords, etc. Here's the relevant [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/3.1/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L33-L56):

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentityCore<TUser>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
    where TUser : class
{
    // Services identity depends on
    services.AddOptions().AddLogging();

    // Services used by identity
    services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
    
    // No interface for the error describer so we can add errors without rev'ing the interface
    services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();

    ...
}
```

Essentially, this boils down to registering an instance of `UserManager<TUser>`, but first registers all of its dependencies. With these services registered, you can retrieve an instance of `UserManager<TUser>` from DI and create users, set passwords, change emails, etc.

`AddIdentity` registers the same services as `AddIdentityCore`, with a few extras:

- Cookie-based authentication schemes for the application itself, external sign-in (e.g. Facebook and Google), and 2FA.
- The `SignInManager`, which effectively sits on top of the `UserManager` as a sort of orchestrator. For example, `PasswordSignInAsync` uses `UserManager` to retrieve a user, verify the password (if set) and then takes care of cookie creation.
- `AddIdentity` itself also takes a `TRole` and registers the services that are necessary for supporting Roles.

Here's the `AddIdentity` [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/3.1/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L38-L102) for completeness:

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
    where TUser : class
    where TRole : class
{
    // Services used by identity
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
    {
        o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
        o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
        };
    })
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, o =>
    {
        o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    })
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme, o =>
    {
        o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme;
        o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidateAsync<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator>
        };
    })
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>
    {
        o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    });

    // Hosting doesn't add IHttpContextAccessor by default
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    
    // Identity services
    services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TRole>, RoleValidator<TRole>>();
    // No interface for the error describer so we can add errors without rev'ing the interface
    services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator, TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TRole>>();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is the core module faster?

Comment: It's not about performance. Either one uses the same core with same performance. However, if you load more features, it will take slightly longer to initialize and take slightly more memory.

Comment: @liquidki the "Core" keyword of "AddIdentityCore" does not indicate it being more up-to-date than "AddIdentity". It only means that it comes with the core functionality, literally.

Answer (score 26):

**AddIdentityCore** is the most minimal way of adding authentication and authorization services to your application. It provides a minimal set of options and is intended for advanced scenarios where you want to have a clean starting point to configure Authentication and Authorization further yourself (assuming you will need further modifications to add more services, etc). It does NOT add some services such as Cookie Schemes, SignInManager, or RoleManager.

Note that the "Core" keyword in this method does not indicate it being more up-to-date than *AddIdentity*. It only means that it comes with the core functionality of Identity, literally. (confusing, I know..)

**AddIdentity** adds everything *AddIdentityCore* adds, with some extra services, namely Cookie Schemes (Application, External, and 2FA Schemes are all registered), SignInManager, and RoleManager. Note that *AddIdentity* adds Role services automatically, unlike *AddDefaultIdentity*.

**AddDefaultIdentity** is (arguably) the most convenient way for adding authentication and authorization services to your application, because it comes with a lot of pre-configured options that are suitable for most applications, and it also calls "AddDefaultUI" to add the default UI components under the "Identity" area. It is suitable for scenarios where you want to get up and running quickly with a reasonable set of defaults and a working UI.

Note that *AddDefaultIdentity* does NOT add Role services, so if you want to use *AddDefaultIdentity* and also want to have Role services to your application (which you most likely do), you must call "AddRoles" explicitly with it, like so;

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => { 
    // options are set here
})
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Important Note: *AddRoles* must be added BEFORE *AddEntityFrameworkStores*, otherwise you will get vague errors and it will be difficult to figure out the cause of the issue.

Comment: Brilliant! But I couldn't get it work in my ASP.NET 8 MVC project. I get a System.InvalidOperationException. Message=Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddRazorPages' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.

Comment: @SinanILYAS the "default UI" in Identity is a set of Razor pages, so you need to call `AddRazorPages` to enable Razor page routing - otherwise the routing middleware won't be able to map requests to those razor pages. You can have Razor pages routing and MVC routing in a project at the same time.

Comment: Im fiddling with this a bit, and when using `AddDefaultIdentity` with JWT tokens I get an Unauthorized 401, but when using `AddIdentity` because I dont need the defaultUI, i get a 404. How can one use `AddIdentity` with getting the 401?

Comment: @Jean-Paul try adding "AddDefaultTokenProviders()", something like: services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
 .AddDefaultTokenProviders();