# Add Asp.net Core Identity to an API secured with Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Identity Server 4 configured for authorization and authentication with ASP.NET Core Identity (`Auth Server`). I also have a separate ASP.NET Core API (`API`) configured to use the `Auth Server`. From a Console App I am able to authenticate to the `Auth Server` using `GrantTypes.ClientCredentials` and use the accesstoken to execute a request to the `API`. Everything works as expected.

I would like to use this `API` as an Identity Management API to add/edit/remove Users, Roles, etc so I configure it using ASP.NET Core Identity, but now when I execute the same request from the Console App, I get a 404 because the `API` is redirecting to the Login screen which doesn't exist (it's an API after all). What this tells me is that the current AccessToken and Identity Server auth is not being used. Which means that my new configuration seems to overwrite the Identity Server one.

API Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityContextConnection");

        //This was added for ASP.NET Identity
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        //This was added for ASP.NET Identity
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Audience = "management-api";
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

How can I have this `API` authenticate and authorize against my `Auth Server` and use ASP.NET Identity at the same time?

Comment: I feel your pain! I can't believe Identity Server doesn't handle user management. Working with Identity Core is almost like rolling your own auth solution as you have to write the controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the use of `services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser>()`. As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361533/addidentity-vs-addidentitycore), `AddIdentityCore` should be used for "adding the services that are necessary for user-management actions", while `AddIdentity` does the same plus all authentication, which was overwriting my Identity Server authentication.

The final configuration:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddUserManager<UserManager<IdentityUser>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```