# Log in with Azure AD and get a UserManager

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I have two websites, a "customer" website that contains local users stored in Identity tables in a SQL Server database, and a "management" website the logs in users via our Azure AD. Both websites share a common view of the SQL database (I put the migrations and DbContext in a shared library).

My management website wants to automatically redirect users to Azure AD if they are not authenticated. This is done in Startup.cs via:

```
// Use AzureAD for authentication
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

So far, so good... The above code causes the website to automatically log in via my Azure AD.

Now for the complication: Code in the the management website wants to manipulate "Identity" users created by the "customer" website. To do this, the management website needs `UserManager` and `RoleManager` instances. But the only way I know to wire up a `UserManager` or a 'RoleManager' is to call `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity`, like this:

```
// Configure Identity
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

// Use AzureAD for authentication
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

This allows me to use DI to get a `UserManager` or `RoleManager` instance elsewhere in the code, **but it turns off the automatic login via Azure AD** and tries to redirect to the Identity login page (which, in my "management" website, doesn't exist).

**How can I configure Identity while retaining the automatic Azure AD login behavior?**

EDIT:

Microsoft tech support is working on this. I'll post the answer when I get it from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AddIdentityCore and inject UserManager and RoleManager separately like below

```
services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(options => 
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppUserContext>();

services.AddScoped<UserManager<AppUser>>();
services.AddScoped<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, RoleStore<IdentityRole, ApplicationDbContext>>();
```

[Reference on AddIdentityCore](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

Difference between AddIdentity and AddIdentityCore [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361533/addidentity-vs-addidentitycore)

Github sample [here](https://github.com/adi555j/test-azure-ad/tree/master)

Comment: Aditya was the Microsoft tech support guy who finally solved this for me. Thank you @Aditya!

Comment: No problem Bob.I had fun working with you. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Identitys authentication theme `Identity.Application` is used in the default authorization policy for your authorized controllers. Try to explicitly set the default authorization policy to use the AzureAD authentication theme, e.g.:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

Edit:
Have a look at the `AddIdentity` extension method in [IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3ea1fc7aac9d43152908d5d45ae811f3df7ca399/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) on GitHub, within that method AddAuthentication is called:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
```

Perhaps you have to overwrite these settings with the corresponding constants from the `AzureADDefaults` in the `AddAuthentication` call on which you call `AddAzureAd` like:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme; // not sure
})
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Comment: This sounded promising, but it doesn't help. As soon as I add the `AddIdentity` code to Startup.cs, it tries to redirect to the login page.

Comment: Do you call AddAuthorization after AddIdentity?

Comment: I wish there was a way to include my code block in the reply, but I haven't figured out how to deal with markdown that requires new lines. Anyway... I've tried various combinations of `AddIdentity`, `AddAuthentication`, and `AddAuthorization`, generally in that order, although I did try calling `AddIdentity` after `AddAuthorization`. All of these combinations, as long as `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity` are present, insist on redirecting to the login page.

Comment: You could update your question with the code. Did you try overwriting the authentication defaults as i mentioned in my edited answer after calling `AddIdentity`?