# Claims principle find first value not working with services addidentity

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing a web API using .NET 5. I have an endpoint in that gets the current user

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> GetCurrentUser()
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email));

        return CreateUserObject(user);
    }
```

Now, if I add the dependency like below, this method works fine.

```
services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(opt =>
        {
            //options go here
            opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
```

However, if I use `AddIdentity()` instead of `AddIdentityCore()` this method fails

```
        // AddIdentity registers the same services as AddIdentityCore, with a few extras:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361533/addidentity-vs-addidentitycore
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(opt =>
        //services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(opt =>
        {
            //options go here
            opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
        .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();


        SymmetricSecurityKey key = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"]));

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = key,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                };
            });
        services.AddScoped<TokenService>();
```

> "statusCode": 500,
> "message": "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'email')",
> "details": "   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByEmailAsync(String email)\r\n   at Spacestation.API.Controllers.AccountController.GetCurrentUser() in F:\\Projects\\Spacestation\\Spacestation.API\\Controllers\\AccountController.cs:line 86\r\n   at lambda_method18(Closure , Object )\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\r\n   at Spacestation.API.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in F:\Projects\Spacestation\Spacestation.API\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 28"

Edit #1
[image]

Edit #2 - The token services

```
public string CreateToken(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
        };

        SymmetricSecurityKey key = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"]));
        SigningCredentials creds = new(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = creds
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    }
```

Comment: Could you pls check if there's `ClaimTypes.Email` in `User`? As we know that `AddIdentity()` contains the implement of `AddIdentityCore()` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55361961) said. And I also found a [similar question here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18348)

Comment: And I also don't know how you get the email when using `AddIdentityCore()` .  Whether or not you set the email as a custom property? And this is my debug screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V97XA.png

Comment: I referred to this tutorial to generate my test project and this is my configure.https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Tc0.png

Comment: So when using `AddIdentityCore` I have these properties in User.
But they are not present in `AddIdentity`
See edit #1

Comment: Could you debug before for User beign authenticated?

Comment: @TinyWang I've also added my token service, is there perhaps a different way token claims need to be set between `identity` and `identitycore`?

Comment: @Adam the test I executed is based on asp.net core 3.1 but not 5, and as this high [vote answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52135130/14574199) said `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)` is for net 5 so I created a new project today and I found it uses `services.AddDefaultIdentity` by default. And I search for the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can work for you, but I added few configurations more and an additional AddAuthentication:

```
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(
        options => {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
            options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
            options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
            options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, act => {
           act.LoginPath = "/identity/account/login";
           act.AccessDeniedPath = "/identity/account/accessdenied";
           act.SlidingExpiration = true;
       });
```

Comment: I added these configurations but I still throws the same error

Comment: I've also added my full configuration for authentication

Answer (score 0):

I newly [created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-web-app-with-authentication) a net 5 mvc project and `Change Authentication to Individual User Accounts` and I found by default it uses `services.AddDefaultIdentity`, so I query the difference between it and `services.AddIdentity` and the result is like

> Calling AddDefaultIdentity is similar to calling the following:
>
> AddIdentity
>
> AddDefaultUI
>
> AddDefaultTokenProviders

And, this works for me :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(opt =>
            {
                opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddDefaultUI();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I added the `AddDefaultTokenProviders()` method to my services, however, I still don't have any claims set in my `User`. I also don't have a `AddDefaultUI()` either. I dont understand why in the core version my claims are being set, but not when using `AddIdentity()`

Comment: I think it's better to report issue to github in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentity?view=aspnetcore-5.0).