# How to leverage EF Core Identity Authentication (and authorization) functionalities without UI, but just API controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to figure if and how, I can leverage the functionalities from EF Core Identity to manage my users in my app.

I have created a React app with ASP.NET Core Web API (preview), that includes 2 projects - the frontend and the backend.

The project is mostly empty.

I want to define my own controllers for `/login` and `/register` endpoints, but I don't want the Identity UI associated with it.

Is there a way to use those packages mentioned above, and how? (like `userManager` and `signInManager`? For handling sessions safely?)

I've been looking around so far but have trouble finding clear answers. Seems like going with JWT is the simplest route...?

If have defined my own `UserModel` inheriting from `IdentityUser`, and have properly set up a `ApplicationDbContext`, and a database connection.

Comment: "I want to define my own controllers for /login and /register endpoints, but I don't want the Identity UI associated with it." What do you mean "don't want the Identity UI associated with it"  ?  Do you want to create UI by yourself ? Or ? Could you explain more ?

Comment: I do not wish to scaffold any of their razor pages. I just want to use a controller, and define some /login, /register, /logout routes for my front end to consume.

Answer (score 2):

Identity by default does not add "default UI", and adding these razor pages is optional. See here where I explained differences between `AddIdentity`, `AddIdentityCore`, and `AddDefaultIdentity` [AddIdentity vs AddIdentityCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361533/addidentity-vs-addidentitycore/75307288#75307288)

In short, if you don't want the UI pages (identity razor pages) to be added to your project, don't scaffold identity. When you scaffold identity, it adds those razor pages under a new area called Identity. Instead, choose between `AddIdentity` or `AddIdentityCore` (I would recommend `AddIdentity`, as it adds more functionality), and simply inject the related services (user manager, signin manager, etc.) into your controllers to get authentication and authorization functionalities in your controllers. Note that you should not use `AddDefaultIdentity` because it automatically calls `AddDefaultUI`, which is what you don't want.

Your Program.cs should look like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then, here is how to perform dependency injection for user manager, as an example. You can inject more identity services the same way, such as signin manager to refresh cookies etc. whenever needed.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
// ...

public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public YourController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    // Your controller actions here...
}
```

As an example, here is how you would use user manager to create a new user through this controller.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(CreateUserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // User created successfully
            // You can redirect or return a success message
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }
    }

    // If ModelState is not valid or user creation fails, return the view with errors
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @emre for this detailed answer. I'll look into this more deeply soon.
My next question would be: Is there a token that is shared to the frontend for them to confirm identity? How do you go about protecting your routes, both backend (I know there's a [Authorize] property you can set for endpoints, does this work with this solution?

Comment: And how how are sessions managed then, and controlled?

Comment: Do we still need to generate JWT?

Comment: @m3.b Session management has nothing to do with authentication and authorization, which is all ASP.NET Core Identity library is concerned with. And using JWT Auth scheme is optional, you can instead use cookie auth scheme. You have to choose one of them (cookie or JWT), or you can also add both of them to the project if you wish.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to round-trip trusted state via an untrusted client. It is done with a JWT (json web token), which is pretty much a json that has been encrypted with symmetric encryption. Only the server knows how to decrypt it, thus it is safe to share this token with anyone (pretty much the same thing is happening with the cookies as well). Luckily for us, Identity does most of the job behind the scenes (such as management of secret keys for encryption, automatically decrypting them in middleware etc.) so it is convenient and relatively easy to set up these auth schemes.

Comment: You should ask a new question if you need further clarification on these topics, and please mark my response as the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Also yes, [Authorize] property is how you protect endpoints. Here is a link to the docs that explains how it works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-7.0