# How to add more fields to ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am using .NET 5 - version `5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10` .

[image]

I customized table `AspNetUsers` success, by this way

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;

namespace shadow.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string AliasName { get; set; }
        public string SecondMobile { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
        public string Avatar { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
    }

}
```

and

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using shadow.Models;

namespace shadow.Data
{
    public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {

        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

I am looking for a similar solution with table `AspNetRoles`. I need add filed `Description` to table `AspNetRoles`, how to archive this? Please guide me how to make change in `ApplicationDbContext`.

**My effort:** I tried

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace shadow.Models
{
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

}
```

but error

[image]

I feel hard when decare `ApplciationRole` to `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: In the exact same method call where you configure `ApplicationUser`, you can additionally configure the class for `IdentityRole`. Perhaps this Q&A helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426278/how-to-use-roles-in-asp-net-core-2-1/50426693#50426693

Comment: I updated information. I feel hard when decare `ApplciationRole` to `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/93749680-85152880-fc24-11ea-83ba-1987b93d8689.png

Comment: Does `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>` work? Where the last parameter `string` is for the type of your identity key.

Comment: It works! https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/93750161-3ddb6780-fc25-11ea-9e5a-34e2ae14115c.png

Comment: Great, will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

As we can see in the [sourcecode](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/EF/IdentityDbContext.cs) `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` does not have a class for `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole>`. It has classes `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` and `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>`. Hence, as described in *point 5* of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#change-the-primary-key-type)

> If a custom ApplicationRole class is being used, update the class to inherit from IdentityRole. For example:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

> Update ApplicationDbContext to reference the custom ApplicationRole class. For example, the following class references a custom ApplicationUser and a custom ApplicationRole:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class ApplicationDbContext :
    IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Where the last parameter `Guid` above is the type of the primary key for users and roles, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-3?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: After alter `string` by `Guid` , I catch error https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/93755421-741ce500-fc2d-11ea-916b-a676b0f0d4c6.png

Comment: For the sake of keeping it the same as documentation, I have kept it as `Guid` in here. For it to work, you can change ApplicationRole class as `public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>` and ApplicationUser class as `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>` or you can make it `string` again.